# Proving $\left|\sum_{n>x/m} \frac{ \chi(n)}{ n^{s}} \right| \leq 2q |s| (m/x)^{\sigma}$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

> $\text{Show}\:\displaystyle\left|\sum_{n>x/m} \frac{ \chi(n)}{ n^{s}} \right| \leq 2q |s| \left(\frac mx\right)^{\sigma}$  where $s=\sigma +it$.

Here is what I tried:

$\displaystyle\left|\sum_{n>x/m} \frac{ \chi(n)}{ n^{s}} \right| \leq \left(\frac mx\right)^{\sigma} \sum_{n>x/m} \left| \chi(n) \right|$.

I dont know how to get the $2qs$ part.  Here, we assume $\chi$ is a character $\mod q$.

Comment: $\sum_{n=N}^\infty \chi(n) n^{-s} = \sum_{n=N}^\infty A_\chi(n) (n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s})$ where $A_\chi(n) = \sum_{m=N}^n \chi(m)$